# No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped

Tags: java, ionic, apk

Al generar la apk firmada me muestra este warning y no genera la apk firmada

No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2044-02-09) or after any future revocation date.

Lo extraño es que 10 minutos antes sí la generó.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que mires esta forma de hacer un timestamp, es un tanto larga y tediosa, pero te aseguro que es la forma mas eficiente, [How do I sign and timestamp a Java JAR file?](http://certhelp.ksoftware.net/support/solutions/articles/17164-how-do-i-sign-and-timestamp-a-java-jar-file-)